# Errors in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a error that keeps happening and I was wondering if any one could help me with it. Attached is my code and the error that keeps happening.

```
import csv

newrow={'Last Sale Date': '', 'Last Sale Amount': '', 'First Name': '', 'Last Name': '', 'Email Adres': '', 'Franchise': '', 'State': '', 'Postal/Zip Code': '', 'Last Web Order ID': '', 'osg_web_dir': ''}
new_field_names = newrow.keys()

with open('SOR935csv_(1).csv', 'r') as f1, open('FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'wb') as f2:
cf1 = csv.DictReader(f1, fieldnames=('CustNo1', 'CustNo2', 'LastOrderDate', 'LastOrderAmount', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'UserNo', 'Email', 'Franchise', 'PrevOrderDate', 'PrevOrderAmount', 'State', 'ZIP', 'Amt1', 'Amt2', 'Amt3', 'SalesPerson'))
cf2 = csv.DictWriter(f2, new_field_names)
cf2.writeheader()
for row in cf1:
    nr = newrow
    nr['Last Sale Date'] = row['LastOrderDate'].strip()
    nr['Last Sale Amount'] = row['LastOrderAmount'].strip()
    nr['Email Addres'] = row['Email'].strip().split(',',1)[0]
    nr['Franchise'] = row['Franchise'].strip()
    nr['State'] = row['State'].strip()
    nr['Postal/Zip Code'] = row['ZIP'].strip()
    nr['Last Web Order ID'] = row['PrevOrderDate'].strip()
    nr['osg_web_dir'] = row['SalesPerson'].strip()
    print nr
    cf2.writerow(nr)



#with open('SOR935csv_(1).csv', 'rb') as f1, \
#     open('FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'ab') as f2:
#    for inrow in f1:
#        outrow = {
#        outrow[0] = str(inrow[2])
#        f2.write(', '.join(outrow))
```

[image: error report]

Comment: Looks like a typo: see `Email Adres` and `Email Addres`.

Comment: close as typo. `'Email Adres'` is declared in `new_field_names` but `'Email Addres'` is used in `nr`

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer (by clicking the green tick next to it) that highlights this typo. That's the preferred method of "closing off" a question, rather than adding `**Answered**` to the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `newrow` dict you have 'Email Adres' and your csv has 'Email Addres'. Change it in `newrow` and you should be set.

Comment: Thank you i gess i was typeing to fast and misspelled a word .

Comment: We all do at some point.

Answer (score 0):

FYI there can also be some point at which you want to output only certain columns of your data or you have a csv data file which is missing certain columns that are in your header. In those circumstances you would want to use the extrasaction='ignore' and restval='' options. Of course in your case, it was good that you did not have them set as they would have prevented the ValuError exception.

[14.1.1. Module Contents](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#module-contents)

> class csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames, restval='',
>   extrasaction='raise', dialect='excel', *args, **kwds) Create an object
>   which operates like a regular writer but maps dictionaries onto output
>   rows. The fieldnames parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the
>   order in which values in the dictionary passed to the writerow()
>   method are written to the csvfile. The optional restval parameter
>   specifies the value to be written if the dictionary is missing a key
>   in fieldnames. If the dictionary passed to the writerow() method
>   contains a key not found in fieldnames, the optional extrasaction
>   parameter indicates what action to take. If it is set to 'raise' a
>   ValueError is raised. If it is set to 'ignore', extra values in the
>   dictionary are ignored. Any other optional or keyword arguments are
>   passed to the underlying writer instance.
>
> Note that unlike the DictReader class, the fieldnames parameter of the
>   DictWriter is not optional. Since Python’s dict objects are not
>   ordered, there is not enough information available to deduce the order
>   in which the row should be written to the csvfile.